# " if" in Unity5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a scrip for a game where the player goes over a stone and it changes color, when the color stays the desired color it will open a door. How do I compare GameObject color with the default color?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine;

public class MudarCor : MonoBehaviour {

private Vector4[] cores = new Vector4[] {new Vector4(1, 0, 0, 1), new Vector4(0, 1, 0, 1), new Vector4(0, 0, 1, 1)};
public int cor;
public GameObject pedra1;
public GameObject pedra2;
public GameObject pedra3;
public Vector4[] teste= new Vector4[] { new Vector4(0, 1, 0, 1) };





private void Start() {
    //define a cor inicial da pedra
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Vector4(1, 0, 0, 1);



}
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D player)
{
    if (cor == 2)
        cor = 0;
    else
        cor++;
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = cores[cor];



}
private void Update()
{


    if (teste.Equals( pedra1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color))
    {
       //code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic way to do it is:

```
Color colorA = objA.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;
Color colorB = objB.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;

if (colorA.Equals(colorB))
    ....
```